# Impossible to delete object table "PLAYER_OBJECT",because it doesnt exists or you dont have the right

Tags: sql

Im getting an error at DROP TABLE but I cant figure out why. My table PLAYER_OBJECT is already coded and working but even if the table is created the error on drop table wont go away. What I my doing wrong.

`DROP TABLE PLAYER_OBJECT`

`CREATE TABLE PLAYER_OBJECT()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply put IF EXISTS between TABLE AND PLAYER_OBJECT, like this:

`DROP TABLE IF EXITS PLAYER_OBJECT`

You problably have an error in the creation of you table or you didnt launch your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot IT WORKS and I had in facts an error in my table creation. Thanks a lot